# How to run Django management commands against Google Cloud SQL

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

Currently , I have deployed my django project on google app engine. I need to run `python manage.py migrate` command so that `auth_user` table should be created on my google cloud instance  . But don't know where to run this command.

Comment: Usually you just ssh into the server and run the commands in bash, but I dont know how it works with Google-app-engine. If this is your first django app, you'll find much more documentation and guides about deploying to Heroku, or to a vps such as DigitalOcean.

Comment: @HåkenLid how it's possible?

Comment: @HåkenLid I can't able to find a link regarding ssh into gae project. I'm really stuck on this step.

Comment: I don't know either. That's why I suggested using a different hosting platform. Or you could use djangoappengine? http://djangoappengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html
Looks like it makes it possible to run remote management commands from your local dev installation like this: `manage.py remote migrate`

Comment: classic appengine VM or Managed VM? you can SSH only into Managed VM instances

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I get it right, your app runs on App Engine (sandboxed environment) and uses Cloud SQL.

1) Configure your database in `settings.py` as you can see below.

```
if os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Google App Engine'):
    # Running on production App Engine, so use a Google Cloud SQL database.
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '/cloudsql/project-id:instance-name',
            'NAME': 'database-name',
            'USER': 'root',
        }
    }
elif os.getenv('SETTINGS_MODE') == 'prod':
    # Running in development, but want to access the Google Cloud SQL instance in production.
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'INSTANCE': 'cloud-sql-instance-ip-address',
            'NAME': 'database-name',
            'USER': 'root',
            'PASSWORD': 'password',
        }
    }
else:
    # Running in development, so use a local MySQL database.
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': 'database-name',
            'USER': 'username',
            'PASSWORD': 'password',
        }
    }
```

2) Set environment variable SETTINGS_MODE to prod (or do not set if you want to access your local MySQL server).

3) Run the below command from your machine.

```
$ SETTINGS_MODE=prod python manage.py migrate
```

You can find more details in App Engine documentation - [Management commands](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django?hl=en#management-commands) and [Alternate development database and settings](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/cloud-sql/django?hl=en#development-settings).

Comment: I am using Django 1.9 and I had to use *HOST* instead of *INSTANCE*.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this .. It worked out quite well for me . I used this technique to solve my problem of running migrations on Google App Engine Flexible Environment

Comment: Hi. I can't seem to make this work. And it seems like the only understandable and doable solution I found so far. My only problem is the 2nd step "Set environment variable SETTINGS_MODE to prod" - this is confusing. Where do I set it? In app.yaml (tried it already)? Somewhere in google console (already looked and tried to find where I could..)? Or in settings.py (but it doesn't make too much sense for me)? Any info would help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: How does this compare to the 'dev_appserver'? (docs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/testing-and-deploying-your-app)