# Cannot run manage.py against google cloud sql

Tags: python, mysql, django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-sql

I'm trying to run django commands

```
manage.py makemigrations
manage.py migrate
```

to setup MySQL databases on goodle cloud SQL but it only runs against my local development server.

I've followed the code in the [linked StackExchange thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35153942/how-to-run-django-management-commands-against-google-cloud-sql).

Since this isn't working I've forced the database to cloud SQL by only defining that DATABASE within settings.py and I get the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\FCA\manage.py", line 24, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 345, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 348, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 398, in execute
    self.check()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 426, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 75, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\model_checks.py", line 28, in check_all_models
    errors.extend(model.check(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1170, in check
    errors.extend(cls._check_fields(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 1247, in _check_fields
    errors.extend(field.check(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 925, in check
    errors = super(AutoField, self).check(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 208, in check
    errors.extend(self._check_backend_specific_checks(**kwargs))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 317, in _check_backend_specific_checks
    return connections[db].validation.check_field(self, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\validation.py", line 18, in check_field
    field_type = field.db_type(connection)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 625, in db_type
    return connection.data_types[self.get_internal_type()] % data
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 36, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 184, in data_types
    if self.features.supports_microsecond_precision:
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\features.py", line 53, in supports_microsecond_precision
    return self.connection.mysql_version >= (5, 6, 4) and Database.version_info >= (1, 2, 5)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\utils\functional.py", line 33, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 359, in mysql_version
    with self.temporary_connection():
  File "C:\Python27\lib\contextlib.py", line 17, in __enter__
    return self.gen.next()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 564, in temporary_connection
    cursor = self.cursor()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 231, in cursor
    cursor = self.make_debug_cursor(self._cursor())
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 204, in _cursor
    self.ensure_connection()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 95, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 199, in ensure_connection
    self.connect()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\base.py", line 171, in connect
    self.connection = self.get_new_connection(conn_params)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\mysql\base.py", line 264, in get_new_connection
    conn = Database.connect(**conn_params)
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\MySQLdb\__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
  File "build\bdist.win-amd64\egg\MySQLdb\connections.py", line 193, in __init__
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'thwaites'@'localhost' (using password: YES)")
```

I have obtained an IPv4 address from Google and the user/password can access when I connect with MySQL Workbench

EDIT - below I attached settings.py

```
# Copyright 2015 Google Inc. All rights reserved.
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '-c&qt=71oi^e5s8(ene*$b89^#%*0xeve$x_trs91veok9#0h0'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'coursework',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

# [START db_setup]

# set this if you want to run django commands from development against CloudSQL eg to set up database etc
#make_cloudsql = 'prod'

import os
"""
if os.getenv('SERVER_SOFTWARE', '').startswith('Google App Engine'):
    # Running on production App Engine, so use a Google Cloud SQL database.
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'HOST': '/cloudsql/quizalitious:myfcacoursedb',
            'NAME': 'mydb',
            'USER': 'root',
        }
    }
elif os.getenv('SETTINGS_MODE') == 'prod':
"""    # Running in development, but want to access the Google Cloud SQL instance in production.
DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'INSTANCE': '173.194.228.69',
            'NAME': 'mydb',
            'USER': 'thwaites',
            'PASSWORD' : 'secret',
        }
    }
"""else:
    DATABASES = {
        'default': {
            'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
            'NAME': 'mydb',
            'USER': 'root',
            'PASSWORD': 'secret',
            'HOST': 'localhost',
            'PORT': '3306',
            'OPTIONS': {
                'autocommit': True,
                }
        }
    }
"""
# [END db_setup]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_ROOT='static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

MEDIA_ROOT='media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Comment: Hi, Can you post your settings.py?

Comment: I think `'INSTANCE': <IP>` should be `'HOST': <IP>`

Comment: P.S. You should change your SECRET_KEY since you posted it in a public place...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally sorted this on a temporary basis by exporting my database structure from the development server and importing it into CloudSQL which is fine while the site isn't live but will become a problem if I want to update a live site and keep my data!