# How to run files my files Django/python in Google App Engine Standard Environment ( manage.py, ... )

Tags: python, django, git, google-app-engine

I am running a Django python app locally perfectly but I am lost when I deploy it in Google App Engine.
Indeed, locally I am used to run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

and on Google App Engine I can't find these files in the Google Shell. I use BitBucket as a repo and

```
gcloud app deploy
```

to deploy the code from the repo BitBucket.

However, when I go into Cloud Shell, I can't find my files to run the migrate command.
I could checkout them locally... and I did, but they are not the "same" files...

In Cloud Storage, I can see 2 items, but I can locate them in the Cloud Shell.
hiking-164708.appspot.com
staging.hiking-164708.appspot.com

and I want to run the migrate cmd, because I have an issue with my /admin, other TABLEs work...

So my question:
Where is my manage.py file ?

here is my app.yaml

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true

handlers:
- url: /.*
script: main.application

libraries:

- name: django
version: "1.4"
- name: MySQLdb
version: "latest"

env_variables:
DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: 'ghiking.settings'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that you run your migrations from your dev machine connected to your Cloud SQL instance.

1) Extend `settings.py`

```
elif os.getenv('SETTINGS_MODE') == 'prod':
# Running in development, but want to access the Google Cloud SQL instance in production.
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'INSTANCE': 'cloud-sql-instance-ip-address',
        'NAME': 'database-name',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
    }
}
```

2) Run migrations against Cloud SQL

*nix -

```
$ SETTINGS_MODE=prod python manage.py migrate
```

Windows

```
set SETTINGS_MODE=prod
python manage.py migrate
```

Please also see the answer to [How to run Django management commands against Google Cloud SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35173006/7947020) and [Setting up your local environment](https://cloud.google.com/python/django/appengine#setting_up_your_local_environment)

Comment: Yes, indeed the point is to use Database remotely with local execution.
But on Windows, define the variable and execute Python gives an error stating that this is not a command of course...

How can I set-up the SETTINGS_MODE variable on Windows ?

Comment: @RémiDelpierre You should be able to use the set command in a command prompt session. I edited the answer to include Windows.